# EJB 3.1 - Inject Session Scope Pojo

Tags: java, jboss7.x, resteasy, ejb-3.1, session-scope

Using: EJB 3.1, JBoss AS 7, RestEasy.

I have a session scoped bean which I want to user to store user informations for the session.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
@SessionScoped
public class LoggedInUser implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    ...
}
```

If the user open my web application a filter extract header informations (application runs behind a webseal) which contains a user identification. I need to create a logged in user object (see LoggedInUser above) there (after calling ldap). Afterwards I want to inject this LoggedInUser object in different @Stateless Beans, but LoggedInUser is always "empty" (members are null).

Inject sample:

```
@Path("/country")
@Stateless
public class CountryController extends AbstractController {
@Inject
private Logger LOGGER;
@Inject
private LoggedInUser loggedInUser;
//@Inject dont work too..
//private Instance<LoggedInUser> loggedInstance
```

What do Im wrong?

Comment: You should show the code that you think should fill LoggedInUser fields.

Comment: The code for filling LoggedInUser fields not existing yet. Is it possible to change LoggedInUser fields after the bean is instanced? Or do I have to add a @PostContruct method into LoggedInUser (so I had to read the header there too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the comment and the question - you need some help with EJB concepts.

@SessionScoped beans are beans that have one instance per session. Every @Inject with bean like that during one session will reference the same object. That's it however - if you want your bean to contain some information specific to that session, you will need to put it there yourself, using setters or other methods like you would do in every normal Java class.

Comment: I know that a session scoped bean has one instance per session, my problem is that I cannot change values of LoggedInUser. For example, if I call loggedInUser.setId("myNewId") at CountryController the value will not be changed. I can watch it while debugging with eclipse, I call setId but the value not change. Initial the object get instanced with default constructor.

Comment: So you can call `loggedInUser.setId("myNewId");` `System.out.println(loggedInUser.getId());` and the Id is not set? Also, that is exactly the part I originally wanted you to add to the question - the code that fills loggedInUser and does not work

Comment: Well I tried filling LoggedInUser in different ways. Tried to set id in LoggedInUser#LoggedInUser (constructor), LoggedInUser#initial (@PostConstruct) or just tried to set values at CountryController#someMethod() with this.loggedInUser.setId("testId"). It would help if you just tell me how I should store user informations, I dont know if I doing right or not. Best practise?

Comment: `I cannot change values of LoggedInUser` suggests that something is wrong, since all the methods you mention should work. What is your test case, how did you determine that what you did did not work?

Comment: My dear, sysout show correct result! Just eclipse cannot show LoggedInUser values..My sorry, thanks for your time.